# Firefox ChromeWorker not loading script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I have a requirement where I need to communicate with native code to perform some operations. I have been successful by using JS-Ctypes and things are panning out as expected. Since the communication from my web application with the native code takes some time, thus blocking the main JS thread consequently freezing the UI.

Thus I need to create a separate thread to be delegated with the communication with the native code and post back results to the main thread which will give the appropriate feedback to the user. Firefox [ChromeWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/ChromeWorker) are exactly what I need to use, since they are independent threads with access to JS-Ctypes.

My problem is that for the life of me, I can't seem to load a script using that approach. This is what I currently have:

main.js

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');                         
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var worker = new ChromeWorker("js/fpman/myworker.js");
worker.onmessage = function(e){
      console.log(e.data);
};

worker.postMessage('start');
```

myworker.js

```
self.onmessage = function(e){
   var sum = 1 + 1;
   postMessage("Sum is " + sum);
};
```

When that code runs in the main JS, I get this error on firebug console

```
Failed to load script: http://localhost:8080/myapp/js/fpman/myworker.js (nsresult = 0x805303f4)
```

Point to note, when I use a normal worker thread i.e

```
var worker = new Worker("js/fpman/myworker.js");
```

the js file (myworker.js) is loaded fine and I get the expected result, but of course that doesn't suffice my needs since a normal worker doesn't have access to JS-Ctypes. So it seems the problem is how am creating the ChromeWorker. Could someone please enlighten me on how to appropriately instantiate and use the ChromeWorker Object from an application. I have seen a lot of reference of usage of ChromeWorker in extensions, but that is not what I want, I want to use the ChromeWorker in my web application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That particular error is NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI

I don't believe what you are doing will work, and I know it won't work very soon in Firefox because enablePrivilege is going away completely.

Comment: Mike, any idea why a normal Worker object can load the script while a ChromeWorker fails to load the same script?

hmmm, about your second comment, going forward how are we going to be accessing privileged operation from our web apps?

Comment: > any idea why a normal Worker object can load the script while a ChromeWorker fails to load the same script.

Well, you're trying to load an external URL as a chrome file, giving it chrome privileges. I don't believe that's allowed.

> going forward how are we going to be accessing privileged operation from our web apps

You're going to be expected to write an add-on and add the functionality there and call it from your web app. All your users will have to install the add-on (not ideal, I know).

Feel free to voice your opinion - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=757046

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this from an add-on (we're at FireFox 25 in the mean time), and I also get "Failed to load script: file:///C:/" etc. with the correct path to the file I want to load.